# Rails Model Store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have User model in my project (project was transferred to me and I don't fully understand why this problem is happening).

When User trying to delete his own record or if I do this from Rails console `User.find(1).destroy' I see log:

```
User Store (16.0ms)  {"id":1}
```

But record don't disappears from DB, I don't understand what is it and why it happening.

**EDIT**

I've created safe delete method with AASM gem. And when state is changed to removed (in record it looks like `state: 0` (for created) and `state: 1` (for removed)) I can't find User with id 1 through console. But when I go to MySQL console I see record with state 1.

Comment: What's the issue? That would seem to be expected behavior?

Comment: @DaveNewton Is it not the basic behavior if I do `User.destroy` it must be deleted from db?

Comment: @DaveNewton And thats now the behavior what I expect if I want to change state. It still should be accessible from Rails console.

Comment: ... The whole point of safe-deleting is to *not* remove it from the DB. Most safe-delete gems have a default scope that excludes "deleted" instances. That's what safe deleting is *for*.

Comment: @DaveNewton Ok, lets split. First, if I do `User.destroy` I should not see record in DB, but I do (I did it before created safe delete with AASM). Second, if I update attributes of record (state with AASM gem), they should not hide record from Rails console, but still it do

Comment: Second point first: this isn't correct. The entire point of a safe-delete is to remove it from your default Rails queries. If you do an unscoped query you'll see it--but that defeats the purpose of safe-delete. Obviously safe-deleting won't remove it from the DB. If *before* any safe-delete was in place you did a `destroy` and it *wasn't* removed from the DB, then something was altering your code's behavior, because that's precise what `destroy` does. If it didn't, it's almost certainly (a) not a Rails bug and (b) likely programmer error.

Comment: @DaveNewton so you saying one of gem modified default scope for rails query?

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, checked. You right. Can you post answer, so I could up your rating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like expected behavior.

Most safe-delete mechanisms amend the default scope to exclude "deleted" records. Performing an unscoped query would return both the "deleted" and non-"deleted" records.

Since the records are not physically removed from the DB anything that bypasses the Rails scope mechanisms (like a query from a DB console or IDE) would show the "deleted" records along with whatever flag/state is used to indicate they've been (virtually) "deleted".

If, before implementing a safe-delete mechanism, a `destroy` did *not* remove the record *from the database*, then there's something else in the system that's doing some form of safe-delete. Default `destroy` behavior will physically remove the record from the DB.